# How To Pass Information from DT Table into TabBox on Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

Need Help I would like to Pass through information from DT Table to TabBox on Shiny Dashboard, with the flow like this: TextInput >> DT Table >> TabBox

I already could do that but the issue that any other information that I have been upload is disappear

[image]

after button submit information has been clicked it will update the DT Table and the Tab box

[image]

for the Tab Box
[image]

But the issue is, another information that I have been upload is disappear

[image]

My goal is to Pass Through the information from Text Input > DT Table > TabBox without losing any information for another file that I have been upload, any solution is really appreciated

**UPDATE**

I give more detail what information that disappear

[image]

```
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader( title = "PRD"),
  dashboardSidebar(uiOutput("sidebarpanel")),
  dashboardBody(shinyjs::useShinyjs(), uiOutput("body"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$sidebarpanel <- renderUI({ 
    
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Entry Data", tabName = "ED", icon = icon("th")),
      menuItem("Main Info", tabName = "MI", icon = icon("th"))
    )
    
    })
  
  output$body <- renderUI({
    
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName ="ED", 
              fluidRow(
                box(width = 12,
                    fileInput(inputId = "FLK",
                              label = "Upload Document",
                              accept = c(".xlsx",".csv")
                    )),
                box(width = 12, title = "Image 1", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                    collapsible = TRUE, 
                    fileInput("myFile1", "Upload an image file", accept = c('image/png', 'image/jpeg')),
                    actionButton('reset1', 'Clear Image'),
                    div(id = "image-container1", style = "display:flexbox")),
                box(width = 6, title = "Input Company Information", status = "warning", solidHeader = TRUE, 
                    collapsible = TRUE, 
                    textInput("PCI_CC", "Company Info A"),
                    br(),
                    textInput("PCI_CN", "Company Info B"),
                    br(),
                    textInput("PCI_IS", "Company Info C"),
                    br(),
                    textInput("PCI_AN", "Company Info D"),
                    actionButton("doSUBMIT", "Submit Information")),
                box(width = 12, title = "Company Information", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                    collapsible = TRUE, dataTableOutput('content_PCI'))
              )),
      tabItem(tabName ="MI", class = "active",
              fluidRow(
                tabBox(
                  title = "Information Tab",
                  id = "tabset1", height = "400px",
                  tabPanel("Information", 
                           "Company Info A :", PCI$data[1, 2],
                           br(),
                           br(),
                           "Company Info B :", PCI$data[2, 2],
                           br(),
                           br(),
                           "Company Info C :", PCI$data[3, 2],
                           br(),
                           br(),
                           "Company Info D :", PCI$data[4, 2],
                           br(),
                           br(),
                           "Last Updated :", PCI$data[5, 2]
                           
                ))))
      
      
    )
    
    
  })
  
  ########################## UPLOAD IMAGE #####################################
  
  observeEvent(input$myFile1, {
    inFile <- input$myFile1
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return()
    
    b64 <- base64enc::dataURI(file = inFile$datapath, mime = "image/png")
    insertUI(
      selector = "#image-container1",
      where = "afterBegin",
      ui = img(src = b64, width = 100, height = 100)
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$reset1, {
    removeUI(
      selector = "#image-container1 > *",
      
      
    )
  })
  
  #######################  INFO TABLE ##########################################
  PCI <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
  
  data_PCI = data.frame(
    Item = c('Company Info A', 'Company Info B', 'Company Info C', 'Company Info D', 'Last Updated'),
    Description = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
  )
  
  PCI_Data <- reactive ({
    data_PCI
  })
  
  observe({
    PCI$data <- PCI_Data()
  })
  
  
  output$content_PCI <-  DT::renderDataTable({
    PCI$data %>%
      datatable(editable = list(target = "cell", disable = list(columns = c(0,1))), options = list(paging = FALSE))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$doSUBMIT, {
    
    PCI$data[1, 2] <<- input$PCI_CC
    PCI$data[2, 2] <<- input$PCI_CN
    PCI$data[3, 2] <<- input$PCI_IS
    PCI$data[4, 2] <<- input$PCI_AN
    PCI$data[5, 2] <<- format(Sys.time(), "%a %b %d %X %Y")
    
    
  })

  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**UPDATE2**

I already found the solution, so the image file will not disappear

```
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader( title = "PRD"),
  dashboardSidebar(uiOutput("sidebarpanel")),
  dashboardBody(shinyjs::useShinyjs(), uiOutput("body"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$sidebarpanel <- renderUI({ 
    
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Entry Data", tabName = "ED", icon = icon("th")),
      menuItem("Main Info", tabName = "MI", icon = icon("th"))
    )
    
  })
  
  output$body <- renderUI({
    
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName ="ED", 
              fluidRow(
                box(width = 12,
                    fileInput(inputId = "FLK",
                              label = "Upload Document",
                              accept = c(".xlsx",".csv")
                    )),
                box(width = 12, title = "Image 1", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                    collapsible = TRUE, 
                    fileInput("myFile", "Choose a file", accept = c('.jpg')),
                    uiOutput("imgview1")),
                box(width = 6, title = "Input Company Information", status = "warning", solidHeader = TRUE, 
                    collapsible = TRUE, 
                    textInput("PCI_CC", "Company Info A"),
                    br(),
                    textInput("PCI_CN", "Company Info B"),
                    br(),
                    textInput("PCI_IS", "Company Info C"),
                    br(),
                    textInput("PCI_AN", "Company Info D"),
                    actionButton("doSUBMIT", "Submit Information")),
                box(width = 12, title = "Company Information", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                    collapsible = TRUE, dataTableOutput('content_PCI'))
              )),
      tabItem(tabName ="MI", class = "active",
              fluidRow(
                tabBox(
                  title = "Information Tab",
                  id = "tabset1", height = "400px",
                  tabPanel("Information", 
                           "Company Info A :", PCI$data[1, 2],
                           br(),
                           br(),
                           "Company Info B :", PCI$data[2, 2],
                           br(),
                           br(),
                           "Company Info C :", PCI$data[3, 2],
                           br(),
                           br(),
                           "Company Info D :", PCI$data[4, 2],
                           br(),
                           br(),
                           "Last Updated :", PCI$data[5, 2]
                           
                  ))))
      
      
    )
    
    
  })
  
  ########################## UPLOAD IMAGE #####################################
  
  observe({
    req(input$myFile)
    
    file.copy(input$myFile$datapath,"www\\img1", overwrite = T)
    
    # output$imgview1 <- renderUI({
    #   tags$img(style="height:1200px; width:100%", src="img1\\0.png")
    
    b64 <- base64enc::dataURI(file = "www\\img1\\0.jpg")
    # insertUI(
    #   selector = "#image-container1",
    #   where = "afterBegin",
    #   ui = img(src = b64, width = 100, height = 100)
    # )
    
    output$imgview1 <- renderUI({
      tags$img(src = b64, width = "400px", height = "400px")
    })
    
    
  })
    
  
  #######################  INFO TABLE ##########################################
  PCI <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
  
  data_PCI = data.frame(
    Item = c('Company Info A', 'Company Info B', 'Company Info C', 'Company Info D', 'Last Updated'),
    Description = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
  )
  
  PCI_Data <- reactive ({
    data_PCI
  })
  
  observe({
    PCI$data <- PCI_Data()
  })
  
  
  output$content_PCI <-  DT::renderDataTable({
    PCI$data %>%
      datatable(editable = list(target = "cell", disable = list(columns = c(0,1))), options = list(paging = FALSE))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$doSUBMIT, {
    
    PCI$data[1, 2] <<- input$PCI_CC
    PCI$data[2, 2] <<- input$PCI_CN
    PCI$data[3, 2] <<- input$PCI_IS
    PCI$data[4, 2] <<- input$PCI_AN
    PCI$data[5, 2] <<- format(Sys.time(), "%a %b %d %X %Y")
    
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
  observeEvent(input$doSUBMIT, {
    PCIdata <- data_PCI
    PCIdata[1, 2] <- input$PCI_CC
    PCIdata[2, 2] <- input$PCI_CN
    PCIdata[3, 2] <- input$PCI_IS
    PCIdata[4, 2] <- input$PCI_AN
    PCIdata[5, 2] <- format(Sys.time(), "%a %b %d %X %Y")
    PCI$data <<- rbind(PCIdata,na.omit(PCI$data))
  })
```